# How to register Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS dll in Windows server without SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, windows-server-2012

We have a Windows server where we are reading some SSIS packages and processing them through a web app eg:

```
SSIS.Application app = new SSIS.Application();
SSIS.Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(txtSSISPackagePath.Text.Trim(), null);
pkg.EnableConfigurations = true;
string ConfigurationFilepath = txtSSISPackagePath.Text.Trim().Replace(".dtsx", ".dtsConfig");
pkg.ImportConfigurationFile(ConfigurationFilepath);
pkg.Execute();
```

We have installed the .NET Framework but no Visual Studio or SQL Server on this server. We are getting an error while running this project on the server:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When we verified in the GAC and Assembly folder, this dll is in fact missing. We have copy pasted the assembly from local but it didn't work both in bin folder and in Assembly/GAC folder. Also tried register with GACUtil but that tool is not available in the server.

Is there any way to add this dll to resolve the reference problem like registering this dll or installing some sdk (not SQL Server) to resolve this problem? 
NOTE:

- We are using .NET framework 4.6.1
- SSIS = Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.Runtime
- It was working in 2008 Server (no SQL installed) and now its not working 2012 Server

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "reading some SSIS packages and processing them through a web app" and what exactly you are trying to do? You may need to install SQL Server to execute SSIS packages.

Comment: @Piotr, I have added more information

Comment: You need a sql server license to execute ssis packages. Any answer to your question might be crossing some "thin" red lines....